# Custom carrier module not showing carrier at front side prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, carrier

In the admin, I see the carrier but in the front office part on the shipping step, the carrier it’s not showing.

This is my custom carrier configuration

The shipping cost is calculated according to the weight and the tax rule No tax will be applied.

This carrier can deliver orders from 0.000000 KGS to 1000000.000000 KGS. If the order is out of range, the behavior is to apply the cost of the highest defined range.

Also allowed for all Zones

Please help me to show custom added carrier on front site.

Comment: Maybe carrier is just being set as disabled? or the shipping country you are using for the order is not linked to any valid zone for that carrier ?

Comment: Carrier is not set disabled, all zones are allowed